# Add images in options and questions in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an online quiz. I created a basic javascript quiz but am not able to add images in questions and options. How to add images into questions and answers? Also I want to embed the quiz with my front end. I am not getting how to do that? 
Below is my javascript quiz. Please tell me how to add images in question and answer. Sample images added would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
div#test{ border:#000 1px solid; padding:10px 40px 40px 40px; }
</style>
<script>
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
var questions = [
    [ "What is 10 + 4?", "12", "14", "16", "B" ],
    [ "What is 20 - 9?", "7", "13", "11", "C" ],
    [ "What is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A" ],
    [ "What is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "C" ]
];
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
function renderQuestion(){
    test = _("test");
    if(pos >= questions.length){
        test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
        _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
    }
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
    question = questions[pos][0];
    chA = questions[pos][1];
    chB = questions[pos][2];
    chC = questions[pos][3];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}
function checkAnswer(){
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
        if(choices[i].checked){
            choice = choices[i].value;
        }
    }
    if(choice == questions[pos][4]){
        correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2 id="test_status"></h2>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Img" html tag and specify the path of the image to show your Question and Option Images.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
div#test{ border:#000 1px solid; padding:10px 40px 40px 40px; }
</style>
<script>
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
var questions = [
    [ "What is 10 + 4? <br> <img src='http://batr.org/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderpictures/quiz_icon.gif'/>", "12 &nbsp <img src='http://batr.org/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderpictures/quiz_icon.gif' height=30px width=30px/>", "14", "16", "B" ],
    [ "What is 20 - 9?", "7", "13", "11", "C" ],
    [ "What is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A" ],
    [ "What is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "C" ]
];
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
function renderQuestion(){
    test = _("test");
    if(pos >= questions.length){
        test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
        _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
    }
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
    question = questions[pos][0];
    chA = questions[pos][1];
    chB = questions[pos][2];
    chC = questions[pos][3];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}
function checkAnswer(){
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
        if(choices[i].checked){
            choice = choices[i].value;
        }
    }
    if(choice == questions[pos][4]){
        correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2 id="test_status"></h2>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```